# TaskFactory.StartNew versus ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

Tags: .net, performance, task, threadpool, taskfactory

Apparently the [`TaskFactory.StartNew`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=net-6.0) method in .NET 4.0 is intended as a replacement for [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem?view=net-6.0) ([according to this post, anyway](https://web.archive.org/web/20160326011516/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/27/9913610.aspx)). My question is simple: does anyone know why?

Does `TaskFactory.StartNew` have better performance? Does it use less memory? Or is it mainly for the additional functionality provided by the `Task` class? In the latter case, does `StartNew` possibly have *worse* performance than `QueueUserWorkItem`?

It seems to me that `StartNew` would actually potentially use *more* memory than `QueueUserWorkItem`, since it returns a `Task` object with every call and I would expect that to result in more memory allocation.

In any case, I'm interested to know which is more appropriate for a high-performance scenario.

Answer (score 7):

Performance is a ... depends.  If you are doing a lot of parallel tasks, then .net 4 tasks will perform better, plus give you more fine grained control (more robust cancellation, ability to wait on multiple tasks simultaneously, ability to create parent/child task relationships, Ability to specify LongRunning, etc.. etc.. etc..)

Additionally, the ability to specify your own TaskScheduler means you can customize it for your needs.  The built-in task scheduler is far more multi-core aware than the old ThreadPool.

As for using more memory.  Every thread reserves a minimum of 1MB of memory, the tiny amount used to store a task object is inconsequential.  I really would think that's the last of your worries.

Comment: AFAIK default TaskScheduler uses a ThreadPool and there is no difference between them when you want multi-core support. The guy has even made some tests: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5219311/152291

Answer (score 6):

TaskFactory.StartNew is more appropriate for a high performance scenario.

You gain a productivity benefit by the set of classes in System.Threading.Tasks and the care that went into their design + integration with the parallel loops and options.

You'll also gain a performance benefit because System.Threading.Tasks are built on top of work stealing in the thread pool which is better for locality (when it matters).

-Rick

Comment: Hi Rick, can you please tell me, when I use Task.Factory.StartNew, does this takes thread from a pool and I have 1 less thread in my pool? Thanks

Comment: Task.Factory.StartNew will use the .net thread pool so yeah the thread will come from the pool

Comment: Is there any way to start new thread  which will not be taken from thread pool?

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to start some logging process, after user submits a form and I don't want him to wait until logging is finished. So I start new thread for that purpose and do all logging in background, so main thread is free and user gets response faster.

Answer (score 2):

Just from the looks of things, the Task classes were designed to work with the new parallel features in .Net 4.  It also looks like you can use `Action` or `Action<T>` directly when starting/creating a task.  This is all 100% conjecture, though, based on poking around the docs :).