# Sending multiple requests to a server using multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a task where I form thousands of requests which are later sent to a server. The server returns the response for each request and that response is then dumped to an output file line by line.

The pseudo code goes like this:

```
//requests contains thousands of requests to be sent to the server
string[] requests = GetRequestsString();


foreach(string request in requests)
{
   string response = MakeWebRequest(request);
   ParseandDump(response);
}
```

Now, as can be seen the serve is handling my requests one by one. I want to make this entire process fast. The server in question is capable of handling multiple requests at a time. I want to apply multi-threading and send let's say 4 requests to the server at a time and dump the response in same thread.

Can you please give me any pointer to possible approaches.

Comment: What about something like this, similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960056/trying-to-run-multiple-http-requests-in-parallel-but-being-limited-by-windows

Comment: I'd have a look at the thread pools or the task parallel library. This question has a good discussion of both approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213695/should-i-use-threadpools-or-task-parallel-library-for-io-bound-operations

Comment: Does order matter when writing out the responses?

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) from .NET 4.0 and the new toy [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx), sample code below is showed how you send requests in parallel, then dump response in the same thread by using `ContinueWith`:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var tasks = requests.Select(r => httpClient.GetStringAsync(r).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                ParseandDump(t.Result);
            }));
```

Task uses `ThreadPool` under the hood, so you don't need to specify how many threads should be used, `ThreadPool` will manage this for you in optimized way.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use `Parallel.ForEach` like this:

```
string[] requests = GetRequestsString();
Parallel.ForEach(requests, request => ParseandDump(MakeWebRequest(request)));
```

.NET framework 4.0 or greater is required to use `Parallel`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be done in a consumer-producer-pattern. You could use a `ConcurrentQueue` (from the namespace `System.Collections.Concurrent`) as a shared resource between the many parallel WebRequests and the dumping thread.

The pseudo code would be something like:

```
var requests = GetRequestsString();
var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    Parallel.ForEach(requests , currentRequest =>
    {
        queue.Enqueue(MakeWebRequest(request));
    }
});

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {        
       string response;
       if (queue.TryDequeue(out response))
       {
          ParseandDump(response);
       }

    }
  });
```

Maybe a `BlockingCollection` might serve you even better, depending on how you want to go about synchronizing the threads to signal the end of incoming requests.

Comment: You're doing a busywait on the side of the consumer.  You'd be *much* better served from using a `BlockingCollection`, since you're not doing the waiting properly on your own.